# Adding an overlay image to a certain activity android

Tags: android, xml

I have the following [image](https://gyazo.com/de9136f6fceadc7f32b77c6385b5249b) that I want to put over my current activity i.e. it would be on top of everything else in the activity(I have a google map and I want it to overlay on that). I was wondering if this is possible in android studio as every time I try it, it pushes the rest of the project down to the bottom of the screen. If this is possible I'd really appreciate it if someone would tell me how to accomplish this.
For convince, lets say we named the file mainscreen.png

Comment: Use a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: you can dynamically add a custom dialog on top of your all views

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack, add a dialog dynamically:

```java
   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activityWeakReference.get(), R.style.NewDialog);
   dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity_help);
   dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
   //for dismissing anywhere you touch
   dialog.show();
```

In your style.xml:

```xml
   <style name="NewDialog" parent="AppTheme">
     <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
     <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
     <!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
   </style>
```